# How to get max optical zoom level on iPhone?

Tags: ios, camera

Trying to code an app using iPhone camera, have no idea how to get the max **optical** zoom level: 0.5, 1x, 2x, 3x, 5x(iPhone 15 pro max)

`videoMaxZoomFactor` only returns a big number(including digital zoom, i think), it's not fit for app's need.

What I can guess is the following:

```
0.5：ultra wide

1x: wide angle
2x: wide angle (zoom factor 2)

3x: tele photo 
4x: tele photo (zoom factor 2)
5x: tele photo (zoom factor 3)
```

The app needs to be compatible with multiple devices with different lens, is there a convenient way to get max supported optical zoom level of a device?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/719602

Comment: @DonMag no, it's still hard to tell the max optical zoom level of each device.